# how do you pass a parameter to a function when it is called by reference?

Tags: javascript

I've created a global variable to pass informatin to a method that is called via a method reference

```
d_g.onerror=i_bm_err_fix;
```

I tried passing it the variable like this(below) but it did not work.

```
d_g.onerror=i_bm_err_fix(d_g);
```

All I'm trying to do is have a generic image load if the site favicon does not.

```
function i_bm_err_fix(d_g)
  {
  d_g.src='http://www.archemarks.com/favicon1.ico';
  }
```

Currently I'm using a global variable to pass this info. but this does not seem like good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this should do the trick:

```
d_g.onerror = function() {
    i_bm_err_fix(d_g);
}
```

Comment: I've been battling this part of my code for a while..this works so I'm using it for now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/VUujE/) work?

```
var myFunc = function(myargument){
    alert(myargument);
};

myFunc('Hello, World');
```